# Problem converting PHP Curl to nodeJs request

Tags: node.js, http-post

I have an old PHP curl app which i am trying to convert to NodeJs and request. My current code works fine in PHP and looks like this.

```
$myXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' .PHP_EOL ;
$myXML .= '<!DOCTYPE IAP_Msg SYSTEM "IAP_Msg.dtd">'.PHP_EOL;
$myXML .='<IAP_Msg>';
    $myXML .='<CustomerID>VODEXIPX</CustomerID>';
    $myXML .='<EchoData>';
        $myXML .='<Transaction_ID>00000001</Transaction_ID>';
        $myXML .='</EchoData>';
    $myXML .='<IAP_Query>';
        $myXML .='<DQ_CName>';
            $myXML .="<QueryNumber>$number</QueryNumber>";
            $myXML .='</DQ_CName>';
        $myXML .='</IAP_Query>';
    $myXML .='</IAP_Msg>'.PHP_EOL;


$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array("Content-Type:application/xml"); // cURL headers for file uploading
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.mysecret.com/iap2',
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $myXML,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
);


curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

When i try to create similar request via nodejs and request it fails on remote end so there must be something diffrent the way it is send.

```
let myXML = 
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE IAP_Msg SYSTEM "IAP_Msg.dtd">
<IAP_Msg><CustomerID>VODEXIPX</CustomerID><EchoData><Transaction_ID>00000001</Transaction_ID></EchoData><IAP_Query><DQ_LNP><QueryNumber>${req.params.callednbr}</QueryNumber></DQ_LNP></IAP_Msg>`

console.log(myXML)

const options = {
    url: 'https://www.mysecret.com/iap2',
    method: 'POST',
    data: myXML,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    }
}

    request(options, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
```

the error message is

> 502 Proxy Error
>
> ## Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream
> server.
>  The proxy server could not handle the request
>
> Reason:
> **Error reading from remote server**

Comment: can you provide the error message?

Comment: i added the error to original post, which means it didn't get something the way it expected. Interesting part is when i look at the request i see 0 for content length. even if i set it to a fixed value manualy  _header: 'POST /iap2 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/xml\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: pgetl-api\r\n' +
        'host: www.mysecret.com\r\n' +
        'content-length: 0\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',